# executing perl code from commandline in windows

Tags: perl

i am very new to perl just began to learn when i try to assign a scalar a value and the print it i am facing problem.                                                                                                                                                                                                        I am doing

```
         perl -e "$number=30;"    
         perl -e "print $number;"
```

the output doesnt show anything but when i do

```
         perl -e "$number=30; print $number;"
```

the output shows 30 why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
perl -e "$number=30;"
```

runs the Perl program `$number=30;`, which sets the variable `$number` to 30 and then does nothing with it.

This:

```
perl -e "print $number;"
```

runs the Perl program `print $number;`, which prints the value of the uninitialized variable `$number`.

The key point is that, since these are two completely separate Perl programs, there's no connection between the variable `$number` in the first program and the variable `$number` in the second program. There is no relationship between the two programs, and no communication between them, so they do not and cannot share any variables.

Comment: one more question raukh can i do somthing like this                                                                                                                                           $number=30;                                                               $result = "This is " + "$number";                    print "$result";

Comment: it's easier this: $result = "This is $number"

Comment: @haris: Yup, but the concatenation operator is `.` rather than `+`: `$result = 'This is ' . $number`. (Or just `$result = "This is $number"`.)

Comment: @raukh: but i read in a text about the context of variable in perl he was explaining the output of the above code will be 30 i dont undrestand how?

Comment: @haris: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The output of *what* code will be `30`? (By the way, if you don't mind, I'd appreciate it if you'd spell my username correctly.)

Answer (score 5):

when you execute:

```
perl -e "$number=30;"    
perl -e "print $number;"
```

these are two independent processes, so they don't share information. Variable $number won't be available to the second command.

The other one:

```
perl -e "$number=30; print $number;"
```

Works because it runs in the same execution, and $number is visible to the next print sentence